# Left join two datatable on multiple columns LINQ

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core

How to do left join 2 DataTables based on multiple columns match ?
In order to compare what datarows is not matching in the right table

Part of incremental upload need to bring in just the new rows from source Datatable

Comment: There are a ton of dups for this question

Answer (score 0):

Found a way to use LINQ to do the comparison of two datatables in c# using join (LEFT)

```
 IEnumerable<DataRow> result = (from srcDt in dtSource.AsEnumerable()
                      join dstDt in dtDestination.AsEnumerable()
                      on new { EmployeeID = srcDt["EmployeeID "], Environment = srcDt["Environment"] } equals new { EmployeeID = dstDt["EmployeeID "], Environment = dstDt["Environment"] }
                     into g
                     from row in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
                     where row == null
                     select srcDt);
        // verify if the result has any rows in the dataset
        if (result.Any())
        {
             DataTable dtInserts = result.CopyToDataTable();
             // other code which uses the new datarows to perform inserts
        }
```